# Do not create thumb if source image width/height smaller than thumb width/height

Tags: image, codeigniter, thumbnails

I am thinking does codeigniter image class have built-in or automatically SKIP create thumb
if the source image width/height smaller than the thumb width/height you set.

If not, how to deal with it?

I have done the thumbnail generate but if I upload an width:200px height:200px image and
my thumb setting is width:400px height:400px the thumb will still create and make the thumb
look bad.

edited

```
$config['config_here'];
$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);

if($arr['image_width'] <= $config['width'] && $arr['image_height'] <= $config['height'])     {
//I don't want to resize the image BUT I want it to copy to a filename with thumb_marker
//How to do it because I already have the $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE; at above.
}else{
   $this->image_lib->resize();
}
```

Comment: i think you need to extend image library check in resize method of library $this->orig_width > $this->width or height then you need to resize it. it will work

Comment: @umefarooq Can you see my edited question again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check size before resize:

```
// get image sizes
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($config['source_image']);

// is wide enough?
if ( intval($width) < 400 ) {
    throw new Exception("Your image's height must be equal or greater than 400px");
}

// is high enough?
if ( intval($height) < 400 ) {
    throw new Exception("Your image's width must be equal or greater than 400px");
}

// now we can resize
$this->image_lib->resize();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check your image dimensions before operating
Try this

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($pathToImages);
    if($thumbWidth > $width)
    {
        $new_width  = $width;
        $new_height = $height; 
    }
    else
    {
        $new_width = $thumbWidth;
        $new_height = floor( $height * ( $thumbWidth / $width ) );   
    }


    $config = array(
        'image_library' => 'gd2',
        'quality' => '100%',
        'source_image' => $pathToImages,
        'new_image' => $pathToThumbs,
        'maintain_ratio' => true,
        'create_thumb' => false,
        'width' => $new_width,
        'height' => $new_height
    );              
    $ci->image_lib->initialize($config);
```